# withUnsafeMutablePointer doesn't compile

Tags: ios, swift, pointers

I've been struggling on an issue for some time now. I'm wondering why this code :

```
    private func generateIdentity (base64p12 : String, password : String?, url : NSURL) {

    let p12KeyFileContent = NSData(base64EncodedString: base64p12, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
    if (p12KeyFileContent == nil) {
        NSLog("Cannot read PKCS12 data")
        return
    }

    let options = [String(kSecImportExportPassphrase):password ?? ""]
    var citems: CFArray? = nil
    let resultPKCS12Import = withUnsafeMutablePointer(&citems) { citemsPtr in
        SecPKCS12Import(p12KeyFileContent!, options, citemsPtr)
    }
    if (resultPKCS12Import != errSecSuccess) {
        print(resultPKCS12Import)
        return
    }

    let items = citems! as NSArray
    let myIdentityAndTrust = items.objectAtIndex(0) as! NSDictionary
    let identityKey = String(kSecImportItemIdentity)

    identity = myIdentityAndTrust[identityKey] as! SecIdentityRef
    hasCertificate = true
    print("cert cre", identity)
}
```

compiles, whereas this other one not :

```
private func generateIdentity (base64p12 : NSData, password : String?) {
    let p12KeyFileContent = NSData(data: base64p12)

    let options = [String(kSecImportExportPassphrase):password ?? ""]
    var citems: CFArray? = nil
    let resultPKCS12Import = withUnsafeMutablePointer(&citems) { citemsPtr in // line with the error
        SecPKCS12Import(p12KeyFileContent!, options, citemsPtr)
    }
    if (resultPKCS12Import != errSecSuccess) {
        print(resultPKCS12Import)
        return
    }

    let items = citems! as NSArray
    let myIdentityAndTrust = items.objectAtIndex(0) as! NSDictionary
    let identityKey = String(kSecImportItemIdentity)

    identity = myIdentityAndTrust[identityKey] as! SecIdentityRef
    hasCertificate = true
    print("cert cre", identity)
}
```

XCode tells me that :

> Cannot convert value of type 'inout CFArray?' (aka 'inout Optional') to expected argument type 'inout _'

I really don't see how the 2 codes are different for the citems variable because what I basically just did was to use a NSData argument for the function, thus bypassing base64 string conversion to NSData.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is super-confusing, but the cause of the error resides here:

```
SecPKCS12Import(p12KeyFileContent!, options, citemsPtr)
```

In your second example, with declaring `let p12KeyFileContent = NSData(data: base64p12)`, the type of `p12KeyFileContent` is `NSData`, not `NSData?`. So, you cannot use `!` for `p12KeyFileContent`.

Try changing the line as:

```
SecPKCS12Import(p12KeyFileContent, options, citemsPtr)
```

(`!` removed.)

---

One more.

You usually have no need to use `withUnsafeMutablePointer` to call `SecPKCS12Import`.

Try replacing these 3 lines (in your second example):

```
let resultPKCS12Import = withUnsafeMutablePointer(&citems) { citemsPtr in // line with the error
    SecPKCS12Import(p12KeyFileContent!, options, citemsPtr)
}
```

with this:

```
let resultPKCS12Import = SecPKCS12Import(p12KeyFileContent, options, &citems)
```

The first example code can be rewritten as well.